# Pandas select different rows for each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of Date and three columns as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/01/2019', '02/01/2019', '03/01/2019', '04/01/2019', '05/01/2019', '06/01/2019', '07/01/2019', '08/01/2019'],
               'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
               'B': [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
               'C': [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]})
```

I am trying to select parts of each column based on the date. If not selected looking to return zero. As below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/01/2019', '02/01/2019', '03/01/2019', '04/01/2019', '05/01/2019', '06/01/2019', '07/01/2019', '08/01/2019'],
               'A': [1,2,0,0,5,6,7,8],
               'B': [0,0,0,0,0,16,17,18],
               'C': [21,22,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

In the example So:
'A' would be sliced 01/01/2019 to 02/01/2019 and 05/01/2019 to 08/01/2019 (or no end slice).
B would be sliced 06/01/2019 to 08/01/2019 (or no end slice as that is the last data pointy. 
C would be sliced 01/01/2019 to 02/01/2019.

Comment: so select only column B, then why is column C and A zero?

Comment: Sorry each column has different dates associated. B was just an example. So 'A' would be sliced 01/01/2019 to 02/01/2019 and 05/01/2019 to 08/01/2019 (or no end slice). B as above and C 01/01/2019 to 02/01/2019.

Comment: update question with complete explanation. and What you tried

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understood, you can try and use [`df.where()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+where&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+where&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l4.1203j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
df['B']=df['B'].where(df.Date.between('06/01/2019','08/01/2019'),0)
print(df)

         Date  A   B   C
0  01/01/2019  1   0  21
1  02/01/2019  2   0  22
2  03/01/2019  3   0  23
3  04/01/2019  4   0  24
4  05/01/2019  5   0  25
5  06/01/2019  6  16  26
6  07/01/2019  7  17  27
7  08/01/2019  8  18  28
```

You can do same operations for all column and conditions you want.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best way.

Comment: For curiosity why is this better? You can only do *between* dates, so would have to call this multiple times. Its an added restriction whereas using a mask allows you to only call it once for each column. If its for brevity, this is actually a longer solution compared to my answer I just included the full answer.

If I wrote it in this concise manner it would be:
`B_dates = df['Date'][-3:]` and `df.loc[~df['Date'].isin(B_dates), 'B'] = 0`

Comment: @FChm really depends on the type of data you have and the operations you are doing. upvoted your's. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would generate a Boolean mask:

```
B_dates = df['Dates'][-3:]
df.loc[~df['Date'].isin(B_dates), 'B'] = 0
```

Of course you can iterate over this for any dates and columns you choose.

Here is the output of running this code on your df and printing it:

```
     Date      A   B   C
0  01/01/2019  1   0  21
1  02/01/2019  2   0  22
2  03/01/2019  3   0  23
3  04/01/2019  4   0  24
4  05/01/2019  5   0  25
5  06/01/2019  6  16  26
6  07/01/2019  7  17  27
7  08/01/2019  8  18  28
```